# Restrict AWS Backup Selection by S3 Storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-backup

Is it possible to filter an aws backup selection by storage class for s3 objects? I know it's possible to condition selections based on tags but I can't tell if there's a default resource tag on objects which specify the storage class.

For a bit more context, I want to backup all current versions within s3 without triggering a backup for versions in glacier. I'm aware that AWS backup is [not supported for the flexible glacier storage tier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/s3-backups.html#supported-s3-classes) however I believe AWS backup is still attempting to backup glacier objects and subsequently failing. All backup jobs on buckets with versions in glacier complete with status "Completed with issues". I restored a bucket that "Completed with issues" and the only difference was that the versions stored in glacier were missing.